How can date/time format of Yesod logger be configured?
I have a Haskell Yesod webserver which works perfectly, and logs perfectly1 !
postFailed :: String -> String -> Handler Value
postFailed errorMsg _filename = do
    $logInfoS "(Parser)" (Data.Text.pack errorMsg)
    returnJson (Error "FAILED" errorMsg _filename)

How can I control date/time format? removal of source code loc @(main:Main ...), etc.?
20/Oct/2024:13:12:39 +0000 [Info#(Parser)] Error[< ... omitted ... >] @(main:Main src/Main.hs:76:6)

When I look at the docs, I can't find anything related there.

1 The complete code is here

The logging in general is configured via the makeLogger method of your Yesod instance, which you can override. This is defaultMakeLogger by default, which in turn is defined as
defaultMakeLogger :: IO Logger
defaultMakeLogger = do
    loggerSet' <- newStdoutLoggerSet defaultBufSize
    (getter, _) <- clockDateCacher
    return $! Logger loggerSet' getter

This getter here is simply a IO ByteString that provides the current datetime already formatted, so that's what you'd replace if you want a different format.
You can use newTimeCache from fast-logger for this purpose, that has the right signature and lets you pass in a time format in strftime format. Or you can put in anything else you like, as long as it's a IO ByteString that returns the current time formatted however you like.

So the Yesod logger is essentially wrapping a fast-logger entity ( the LoggerSet ), right? When I try to override getLogger I get an error though: 'getLogger' is not a (visible) method of class 'Yesod'

@OrenIshShalom sorry my bad, it's makeLogger not getLogger. Fixed it in the answer.

@OrenIshShalom also you may want to check the docs there because this is only for application logging, request logging is done via middleware, so if you have a custom logger for your foundation type you'll also want to use that for the logging middleware.

If anyone is looking for the minimal code change, here is the commit based on Cubic's answer
